# Javascript- return an object from a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a function that prompts a user for info and then passes that info to an object. So far it does not seem to be doing that.

```js
// my object constructor
var Person = function (firstName, lastName, areaCode, phone) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.areaCode = areaCode;
  this.phone = phone;
}

// my function to get user info
function getInfo() {
  firstName = prompt("What is your first name: ");
  lastName = prompt("What is your last name: ");
  areaCode = prompt("What is your area code: ");
  phone = prompt("What is your phone number: ");
  var guy = Person(firstName, lastName, areaCode, phone);
  return guy;
}

// calling the function
getInfo();

// test to see if it actually worked
document.writeln(guy.firstName);
```

Comment: you are missing "new" var guy = new Person(firstName, lastName, areaCode, phone);

Comment: Also, you aren't using the return value.

Answer (score 4):

Your code had three problems:

- When you instantiate a constructor, you must use `new`.
- If you declare a variable (`guy`) inside a function, it won't be accessible from the outside. You can

  - Declare it outside, and set its value inside the function.
  - Return it to the outside. In this case you must use the return value.
- You didn't define variables inside `getInfo`. Then, it will only work in non strict mode, and they will become globals, which may be bad.

```js
// my object constructor
var Person = function (firstName, lastName, areaCode, phone) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.areaCode = areaCode;
  this.phone = phone;
}

// my function to get user info
function getInfo() {
  var firstName = prompt("What is your first name: "),
      lastName = prompt("What is your last name: "),
      areaCode = prompt("What is your area code: "),
      phone = prompt("What is your phone number: ");
  return new Person(firstName, lastName, areaCode, phone);
}

// calling the function
var guy = getInfo();

// test to see if it actually worked
document.writeln(guy.firstName);
```

Comment: Missing `var` for the four variables in `getInfo`, don't want them using outer scope

Comment: problem 4, not using the return value of `getInfo()`

Comment: @Oriol getting there – now the first two are local... ;-)

Comment: @bmceldowney I think OP didn't use the return value because he thought that defining `guy` inside `getInfo` made it available outside too.

Comment: Seems possible, but considering the title of the question is about returning an object from a function, it might be worthwhile to point out that he's returning the object correctly but he's just not doing anything with it.

Comment: @Shai I think now it's completely fixed. Don't know why I forget to change some `;` :S

Comment: @Oriol That is correct. I thought defining guy inside the function made is available. I am in the early stages learning JS...lots of mistakes haha. I do thank everyone for the help!